# Link to category page for get_post_meta() values in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a built a couple of wordpress meta boxes called Players, Club and Venues.

I want to display each meta value as a tag at the bottom of a news story and link to a "category" type page. So, for example if you had a Category, football you'd have a link like http://siteurl.co.uk/category/players/

Ideally, I'd like to have something like http://siteurl.co.uk/tag/playername

But I've tried things like that and nothing seems to work. Here is my code currently - how can I wrap an appropriate wordpress template link around the below.

```
$players = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "_players", true);

foreach($players as $player) {
    echo "<a href='" . //link to player like /category/playerID/ . "'>" . $player . "</a>";
}
```

I'm not sure whether a custom meta boxes is recognized at by WP. Is it a category, a tag or taxonomy?